# retrieve data from table and that data use to login

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a login form to log system in php. But I can't do it, below I mentioned my code. I have coded registration form also. It works successfully, but the login form does not works properly. The registration form code is included in the index page. But the login code is include in login.php page.

Help me to solve this problem.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
 aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×</button>
            <h4 style="text-align: center" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                Login & Registration</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;padding-right: 30px;">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#Login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Login">
                            <form  class="form-horizontal" actoin="login.php" method="post" >
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Username</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username2" id="username2" placeholder="Username" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd2" id="pwd2" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        User Type</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="utype" id="utype">
                                            <option selected disabled>User Type</option>
                                            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                            <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                            <option value="Company">Company</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="buttonsubmit" id="buttonsubmit" value="Login">
                                        <a href="">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                            <form  class="form-horizontal" action="index.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Title</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <select class="form-control" id="uutypex" name="uutype">
                                                    <option>Mr.</option>
                                                    <option>Ms.</option>
                                                    <option>Mrs.</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        User Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username1" id="username1" placeholder="User Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Birth Date
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="bdate" id="bdate" type="date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="User Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Mobile
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        University</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uni" id="uni" placeholder="University" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        User Type
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
                                            <option selected disabled>User Type</option>
                                            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                            <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                            <option value="Company">Company</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        GPA</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gpa" id="gpa" placeholder="GPA" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="buttonregister" id="buttonregister" value="Submit and Save">

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                            Cancel
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="OR" class="hidden-xs">
                        OR</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row text-center sign-with">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>
                                Sign in with
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
                                Google
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

php code

```
    <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","internship");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['buttonsubmit'])){

$username=$_POST['username2'];
$password=$_POST['pwd2'];
$type=$_POST['utype'];

$result=mysqli_query($conn,'select * from registration where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'" and usertype="'.$type.'"');


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1 && $type=="Student"){
    header('Location: student.php');
}

else
    ?>
    <script>  alert("Account invalid!!!! Enter valid Username Password and Usertype")</script>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: it's a simple typo; you should pay attention to detail.

Comment: could you debug and see ??

Comment: Could you provide more information? Typically when you run into errors like you this you should see an error message ([maybe you need to enable them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)), did you get one? Can you give us any more information to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","internship");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['buttonsubmit'])){

$username=$_POST['username2'];
$password=$_POST['pwd2'];
$type=$_POST['utype'];

$result=mysqli_query($conn,'select * from registration where username="'.$username.'" and password="'.$password.'" and usertype="'.$type.'"');


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1 && $type=="Student"){
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $result;
    header('Location: student.php');
}

else
    ?>
    <script>  alert("Account invalid!!!! Enter valid Username Password and Usertype")</script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error that you are getting...?
Plus Your code is not secure. You should use php's hash functions to match passwords and use must use PDO to avoid sql injection.

Comment: i havent get eny error message...when i click login button in login form nothing happen....only thing is reloading the index.php page

Comment: I think code should work as you plan it to work I don't understand why it's happening..